# How to Create App for Blog using Android development?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a blog (http://www.topitideas.com) and want to create an android app for it. I know some basics of android development but kindly guide me how is it possible to create an app which shows our blog directly once app starts.

Sorry for bad language but I have needed one of the android app for my blog.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because spam

Answer (score 2):

As per your explanation, if you know basics of android. **WebView** can be an option where you can directly open your blog site through your App.

[Web View Example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/)

Comment: I second this proposition. It also allows a beginner to get more familiar with the development and publishing process for Android without really having to bother about code.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to expose your blog with RSS, parsing it and showing it as a native application with a list of blog posts and a webView with the content inside

Answer (score 0):

webView show's you the content of the your web page in a an embedded widget browser, so you may not be able to control how exactly you display your data in the android application. i would recommend you create get the RSS feeds to your blog most, most blog has it, the feeds are returned in JSON or XML format. you can retrieve(parse) this content from an android app then display it as your desire. in summary, just get an XML or JSON feed from your blog(preferable JSON).